# Hide UIPopover after selecting row

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, hide, uipopovercontroller

I am new to `iPad` developer,

I am using `UIPopover` in my application, when i select any row in my popover, my popover is not getting hide it still in the view, it is getting hide when i touch outside anywhere on the screen.

I want to hide popover after user selects any row.

here is my code snippet,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    for(int index=0;index<=indexPath.row;index++)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        lbl.text=cell.textLabel.text;
    }
}
```

**Logic:** When i select any row of popover corresponding text will be fetched and gets stored into label.

***Any help will be appreciated.***

**EDIT**

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 500, 4)];

popoverPolicyNameTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];// size of tableview inside popover

[popoverPolicyNameTable setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)self]; 
[popoverPolicyNameTable setDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>)self]; 
[self.view addSubview:popoverPolicyNameTable];
[popoverPolicyNameTable release];

[popoverView addSubview:popoverPolicyNameTable];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 200); //size of popover border
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[self.popoverController  presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(350,100, 35, 35) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES]; //size of arrow

[popoverContent release];
[popoverView release];
```

Comment: You must be adding a UIView with a Table inside the popover right?

Comment: @mehul: my app crashes when i write `[myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement something like this

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController1{

    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popoverController=nil;

}
```

Comment: what is `popOverClass` in your code ? i am getting error there.

Comment: popoverclass is your self class in which you have defined the popover.

Comment: Now you can use it as it is.I have edited it for you.Confirmsheet was just a condition that if the popover is not nill then what should be implemented next.

Comment: no effect, in my question i told you i want to hide popover when user selects any row. When this method will be called ? i kept debugger over that method but this method is not being called.

Comment: have you set the delegate for uipopover?

Comment: ya i have added delegate to popover, you can see my **EDIT** in the question. it shows how i am creating UIPopover.

Comment: yes i saw it there..thats why i told you to add popover delegate.You need to check out your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add one variable inside the Class which is having your `UITableView`:

```
id parent;
```

Then properties and synthesize it:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) id parent;

@synthesize parent;
```

Then where you are creating the object of this `ViewController` to add in `Popovercontroller`, do like this

```
myTableViewController.parent = myPopoverControllerObject;
```

Now in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
[parent dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

And you are done!!!

Comment: i wrote: `popoverPolicyNameTable.parent = popoverController;` ,`popoverPolicyNameTable` is a name of tableview and `popoverController` is name of UIpopoverController. after writing this i am getting error, property not found

Comment: property parent not found on object of type UITableview

Comment: see my EDIT in the question, it shows how i am creating UIPopover.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation and notify your delegate that the user selected an item in the list. The delegate will know how to dismiss the view controller.

This approach is better because it's container agnostic, and you can reuse your view controller outside a popover: for example, using navigation controller on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Make Popover controller as class member variable.

Then on clicking on table view click method call dismiss method of that popovercontoller.